# Check if Bitsadmindownload was successfull in Powershell

Tags: powershell

So I am downloading a Binary with Bitsadmin liko so:
`bitsadmin /transfer MyDownloadJOb /download /priority normal $url foobar.zip`
I am searchin for a way to get a message about the statsus (successfull/fail) of the download when the process stops. what could be a possible way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 10 64-bit. PowerShell 5.1

Did my file download? Check if it exists with PowerShell.

```
    if (Test-Path foobar.zip) {
    "download success message here."
    } else {"download fail message here."}
```

Comment: was not exactly what I was looking for, but surely does the trick :)